# Не выполняется код после вполне нормального условия

Tags: java, discord-api, discord, discord-jda

Собственно, после вот этого условия: `if(event.getMessage().getChannel().getId() == "647531811643326511")` ничего не выполняется. Уже пробовал ставить `System.out.println("test")` после этого условия и ничего не произошло. Полный код:

```
if(event.getMessage().getChannel().getId() == "647531811643326511"){
      System.out.println("Wow, a clever person has an idea!");
        event.getMessage().addReaction("");
        event.getMessage().addReaction("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вызовов в

```
event.getMessage().getChannel().getId()
```

`getMessage()` или `getChannel()` или возвращает `null`. Выбрасывается исключение (`NullPointerException`), выполнение прерывается, а исключение потом где-то ловится и давится.

Классика.

Ну и еще одна:

```
if(event.getMessage().getChannel().getId().equals("647531811643326511")){
```

Comment: Спасибо, `equals()` действительно помог.

Comment: @СашаГерасимов Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.